# Are vectors in the $\mathbb R^3$ vector space considered to be position vectors of the points in the 3-dim real space or displacement vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In a text I found the following:

Assume that the two (non-zero) vectors u, v are linearly dependent. This means that one can be written as a linear combination of the other; so, $\mathbf{u} =\alpha\mathbf{v}$. So for two vectors, linear dependence means that they point into the same, or opposite direction; that is they lie on the same line through $\mathbf{O}$.

My confusion is the part where it states that the vectors lie along the line that "goes through $\mathbf{O}$". The only explanation I could come up with was that, they should be position vectors (and thus already on a line to begin with)

Is my assumption correct; or could elements of real vector space be more similar to displacement vectors with a tail that's positioned at a point other than the origin?

Comment: Vectors over the reals can visualized both ways, and a lot of the power of visualization comes from being able to use both as appropriate.

Comment: The only thing that makes something a vector is: that it is an element of a vector space. What we consider a vector space depends only on us making suitable (and hopefully useful) definitions of what it means to add two elements of it, and how to multiply an element with a (real) number. If you can make these definitions for "points", you have a vector space; if you can make them for "equivlaence classes of arrows", you have a vector space; if you can do it for twice continiuously differentiable functions on a neigbbourhood of $\pi$, you have a vector space.

Comment: Have you considered velocity and acceleration vectors?   The tail of these vector are usually placed on the arrow of the displacement vector.  However, All vectors are vector fields... That means you can move them around....assuming they have constant components the direction and length with remain the same no matter where you move the vector to in R^3... that’s why vectors are usually specified  relative to the origin even though they are drawn not at the origin in the case of velocity and acceleration

Answer (score 1):

Considering displacement vectors, instead of vectors with tail in the origin, gives origin to the structure of [Affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space?wprov=sfla1). $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be seen both as a vector space and as an affine space (as in general every vector space is an affine space too)